# Component instance variable value not updating inside subscribe Angular 7

Tags: angular

I am trying to get the current and previous URL of the component and update a component variable based on the URL. When I debug the application, it appears that the components value is getting updated but actually it is not.

The gist of My code below:

dashboard.component.ts

```
show = true;
    constructor(private heroService: HeroService, private router: Router) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.getHeroes();
        this.router.events
        .pipe(
            filter(evt => evt instanceof NavigationEnd),
            pairwise(),
            take(1)
         )
         .subscribe((events: [NavigationEnd, NavigationEnd]) => {
         console.log("Prev", events[0].url);
         console.log("Cur", events[1].url);
         if (events[1].url === "/dashboard" && events[0].url === "/detail/12") {
             console.log("Came here");
              this.show = false;
         }
     });
}
```

dashboard.component.html

`{{show}}`

Please find the stackblitz example of my code:

https://stackblitz.com/angular/qvvrbgrmmda?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdashboard%2Fdashboard.component.html

Steps to reproduce: 
Navigate to any hero page by clicking on the hero name and go back to the dashboard component by clicking on the 'goback' button. Observe in the console.

Note: Imports are ignored, all the import statements are handled properly

Expected Result: The template should display 'false' after updating the component variable.

Actual Result: The template shows 'true' without updating the variable, even if the condition is true.

All of my services are `providedIn: 'root'` and `ChangeDetectionStrategy` is `Default`, but I don't think it will impact anything.

I have tried `changeDetector.detectChanges();`, `changeDetector.markForCheck();` and `ngZone.run();`. But nothing seems to be working. Please suggest to me, what I am doing wrong. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Are you sure `events[1].url` contains only the string `"/tpi/shop"` or if it's only part of the full URL? Could you please post the output of both the `console.log()` statements?

Comment: I was gonna blame detection strategy but if that isnt the case then I;d try to recreate in stackblitz

Comment: URL part and the conditions are fine, only variable is not updating. I will try to recreate the stackblitz and update the question.